# PHP email form without Refreshing Page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, email

I am trying to set up my page so that when I a form is submitted it emails and a message is displayed without refreshing the page.

I have tried to do this using jQuery/Ajax however I cannot get any emails sent now

**Without the Ajax/jQuery, the PHP works just fine but just doesnt include the refresh feature**

Any help would be appreciated

**PHP (submitForm.php):**

```
<?php

    $name = isset($_POST['name']);
    $email = isset($_POST['email']);
    $phone = isset($_POST['phone']);
    $message = isset($_POST['message']);
    $feedback = '';

if($name && $email && $phone && $message) {
    $name = ($_POST['name']);
    $email = ($_POST['email']);
    $phone = ($_POST['phone']);
    $message = ($_POST['message']);
}

    $to = "arshdsoni@gmail.com";
    $subject = 'Soni Repairs - Support Request';

    $body = <<<EMAIL

Hi There!

My name is $name.

Message: $message.

My email is: $email
Phone Number: $phone

Kind Regards
EMAIL;

$header = "From: $email";

if($_POST) {
    if($name == '' || $email == '' || $phone == '' || $message == '') {
        $feedback = "Nothing received!";
    }
    else {
        mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
        $feedback = '*Message Received! You will receive a reply shortly!';
    }
} 

?>
```

**jQuery/Ajax:**

```
function submitForm() {
                var name=document.getElementById('name').value;
                var dataString = 'name'+ name;

                $.ajax({

                    type:"post",
                    url:"submitForm.php",
                    cache:false,
                    success: function(html) {
                        $('#feedback').html(html);
                    }

                });
                return false;
            }
```

**FORM:**

```
<form id="contact" action="#">
                            <h3>Get in Touch:</h3>
                            <h4><span id="star" class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>We aim to reply within 24 hours!</h4>
                            <fieldset>
                              <input name="name" placeholder="Your Name" type="text" tabindex="1" required>
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset>
                              <input name="email" placeholder="Your Email Address" type="email" tabindex="2" required>
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset>
                              <input name="phone" placeholder="Your Phone Number" type="tel" tabindex="3" required>
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset>
                              <textarea id="textarea" name="message" placeholder="Describe your problem...." tabindex="5" required></textarea>
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset>
                              <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit submitBtn" data-submit="...Sending" "return submitForm();">Submit</button>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
```

Comment: What debugging have you done. You should be able to at least determine of the error is in your javascript or PHP code

Comment: @Rasclatt - Sorry I thought I included the form  - NOW added

Comment: @JohnConde - Without the ajax the form works and sends the email, however I want the refresh feature

Comment: If you don't want it to be refreshed , got to do it with ajax.

Comment: Can you put an echo of name, e-mail, phone and message and tell as if all of them get a value? Let us know, what is the feedback you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues:

- if you use`document.getElementById` you must use id on your elements
- Add the data to your ajax request

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#submitBtn" ).click(function( event ) {
    alert('pressed');
        //values
        var name=document.getElementById('name').value;
        var email=document.getElementById('email').value;
        var phone=document.getElementById('phone').value;
        var message=document.getElementById('message').value;
        var dataString = {"name": name, "email":email, "phone": phone, "message":message}

        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"submitForm.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(html) {
                $('#feedback').html(html);
            }
        });
      event.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="contact" method="POST">
    <h3>Get in Touch:</h3>
    <h4><span id="star" class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>We aim to reply within 24 hours!</h4>
    <fieldset>
      <input id="name" placeholder="Your Name" type="text" tabindex="1" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input id="email" placeholder="Your Email Address" type="email" tabindex="2" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input id="phone" placeholder="Your Phone Number" type="tel" tabindex="3" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <textarea id="message" placeholder="Describe your problem...." tabindex="5" required></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <button name="submit" id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<div id="feedback"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['message'])){
    //Post data
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    //mail settings
    $to = "arshdsoni@gmail.com";
    $subject = 'Soni Repairs - Support Request';
    $body = <<<EMAIL

Hi There!

My name is $name.

Message: $message.

My email is: $email
Phone Number: $phone

Kind Regards
EMAIL;

    if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $header)){
        $feedback = '*Message sent! You will receive a reply shortly!';
    }else{
        $feedback = '*Message failed to send';
    }
}else{
    $feedback = 'Missing Params';
}

echo $feedback;
```

Comment: I still keep getting a Refresh I cant seem to figure it out :/

Comment: The php code is in its own file and I have removed the action and I dont get any emails

Comment: Has it been tested and is it working from your side? For a strange reason Im still getting a refresh

Answer (score 0):

I do not see you sending the data to `PHP` file anywhere in your `AJAX` code

**NOTE:** Use `serialize()` function if you want to send all the form data. Else send it separately like

```
var formDatas = {name:"name",email:"emailID"};


function submitForm() {
      var name=document.getElementById('name').value;
      var dataString = 'name'+ name;
      var formDatas = $('#formID').serialize();   // Send form data
         $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"submitForm.php",
            data : {datas : formDatas }
            cache:false,
            success: function(html) {
              $('#feedback').html(html);
             }

          });
     return false;
}
```

Your references

- [jQuery Serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)
- [jQuery ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: I have tested this code, however I find that the page still refreshes?

Comment: I dont think you are sending the datas via ajax..you really have to check on that

Answer (score 0):

This is your ajax, where you went wrong

```
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"submitForm.php",
    cache:false,
    success: function(html) {
        $('#feedback').html(html);
    }
});
```

You forgot to include the data to be posted

```
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"submitForm.php",
    cache:false,
    data {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        phone: $('#phone').val(),
        message: $('#msg').val()
    }
    success: function(html) {
        $('#feedback').html(html);
    }
});
```

The keys `name`, `email`, `message` and `phone` should be as is; because you used `$_POST['name']`, `$_POST['email']`, `$_POST['message']` and `$_POST['phone']`.

The calls`$('#name').val()`, `$('#email').val()`, `$('#phone').val()`, `$('#message').val()` have been made assuming that your input elements have ids `name`, `email`, `message` and `phone` respectively. JS uses ids rather than names.

Refer to [jQuery Ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more details.